# Can't run mongo command on windows

Tags: mongodb, windows, cmd, mongo-shell

I tried t to set up Community MongoDB on my windwos pc. I followed the installation process and tried to set up the environment variables. I copied the pathes from my explorer, so the pathes should be correct. [screenshot of my env](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0y74t.jpg)

Nonetheless I can't use any mongo commands on my command shell. Anytime I try to run "mongo" or "mongodb" or "mongo --version" it says "command is either misspelled or couldn't be found". [screenshot of my cmd shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5J8FG.jpg)

When I use the command "mongod" some strange code appears [screenshot of my cmd shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8gBE.jpg)

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Yes I did a reastart and a reinstallation. Unfortunately still the same problem.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Answer (score -1):

Found the solution: you have to set up mongoshell first and then you can use the command "mongosh" to use it with the windows command. This tutorial helped me set everything up: youtube.com/watch?v=V-d6VAYrjeQ

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is [useful without it](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259): add context around the link so others will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part in case the linked page is unavailable.